# Delay between IPC transaction call and submitting to mempool

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, web3j, txpool, sendtransaction

I encountered a problem, where a web3j transaction was successfully submitted via IPC call and yet, it was not submitted to mempool for another 40 minutes. Etherscan did not show the TX as pending and I am positive that it was not queued in mempool (as in `txpool.status`).

Is there any known buffer in either `web3j`, or `geth` that will queue transactions before sending them to the network?

I am using web3j 5.0.0 and Geth 1.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

Geth nodes can configure what transactions they are willing to accept in their txpool. See the Transaction Pools Options section [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options).

You did not give much details, but I can speculate on a few reasons that could explain a delay.

- The node txpool global slots or accounts slots was full and your gas price was not high enough to replace another pending transaction in the txpool.
- Your gas price was below the gas price limit of the node (minimum gas price at which the tx will be accepted).
- Your transaction was queued because there was a gap in the nonces. This gap was filled 40 minutes later by you.
- There is a bug in you web3j code that delayed sending the transaction.

FYI, I use web3js and a local geth node and my transactions are included in the txpool instantly.

Comment: What means instantly?  I'm seeing delays of up to 100ms until my tx shows up in local mempool. Send via ICP and checked via web3 pending transaction subscription.

Comment: I did not do a specific benchmark, so I don't know what's typical.